# js split, at the end of a line

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im making a web page that, will get the html code of it self and then, replace all the harmful html codes like `<` and `>` and change them to the ascii counterparts so it doesn't skew it up but it looks write to the user also.

I need it to sperate the lines, by ether using the break line html code `<br />` or some other way, I know how many lines I have by using `themehtml.split("\n");`

So the question is 'I need a way to add a line break at the end of the line'

This Is my most of my js code that kind of helps the question a bit

```
$(".edit_html_button").click(function()
                {
                    var themehtml = $(".wrapper").html();
                    var oldhtml = _grubber_blog.html();

                    themehtml = themehtml.replace(/</g, "&#60;"); //slowly removing html codes
                    themehtml = themehtml.replace(/>/g, "&#62;"); //slowly removing html codes
                    themehtml = themehtml.split(' ').join('&#32;');//slowly removing html codes

                    themehtml = ("<div class='numberboxleft'></div><div class='edit_theme' contenteditable='true'>"+themehtml+"</div>");

                    themehtml = themehtml.split("\n");  

                    //alert(themehtml);

                    _grubber_blog.css("background-color", "#fff");
                    $("#tiptip_holder").remove();   
                    $("._grubber_blog_customize").html(" ");    
                    $("._grubber_blog_customize").html(themehtml);

                    //adds the numbers up the left side

                    var e = 0;
                    var lenght = themehtml.length;
                    var numbers = "";

                    while (e < lenght){
                        numbers = $(".numberboxleft").html();
                        $(".numberboxleft").html(numbers + e + "<br />");
                        e++;
                    }

                });
```

Comment: I found the answer I'll Post it for some people

Comment: `themehtml.split("\n").join('<br>')`

Comment: omg, it was that simple, i've been stuck on this for like half a hour oh no... :-D, Thanks though @adeneo

Comment: @adeneo you should probably make your comment an answer, so it can be accepted and this question can be closed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace newlines with html breaks you split on newlines and then join the array with html breaks:

```
themehtml.split("\n").join('<br>')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I used the `$.each` function like so...

```
$.each(themehtml, function(){
                        var grad =  $("._grubber_blog_customize").html();                   
                        $("._grubber_blog_customize").html(grad+this+"<br />");             
                    });
```

This will gradualy add the striped html code to the div and make it look like its line by line